# Using python midi for python 3 requires an integer when writing to disk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, midi

When I run `midi.write_midifile("example.mid", pattern)` I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\guest01\Desktop\python\audio stuff\onset test.py", line 33, in <module>
    midi.write_midifile("example.mid", pattern)
  File "C:\Users\guest01\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\midi\fileio.py", line 162, in write_midifile
    return writer.write(midifile, pattern)
  File "C:\Users\guest01\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\midi\fileio.py", line 110, in write
    self.write_track(midifile, track)
  File "C:\Users\guest01\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\midi\fileio.py", line 124, in write_track
    buf += self.encode_midi_event(event)
  File "C:\Users\guest01\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\midi\fileio.py", line 152, in encode_midi_event
    ret += bytearray(event.data)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

My code looks like this:

```
with open("new.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
    file = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in file:
        if row:
            print(''.join(row))
            ticktime = int(float(''.join(row))*1000)
            note = midi.NoteOnEvent(tick=ticktime, velocity=100, pitch=random.choice(notes))
            track.append(note)

eot = midi.EndOfTrackEvent(tick=1)
track.append(eot)

print(pattern)

midi.write_midifile("example.mid", pattern)
```

I'm not sure why it says `an integer is required` please could anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Have you looked into line 152 of the file "C:\Users\guest01\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\midi\fileio.py"? Who knows, maybe you can figure it out yourself.

Comment: You describe how you construct track, but then write pattern to file not track to the file.  Where does pattern come from?

Comment: `midi` appears to be a 3rd-party package that you installed.  What does the doc for `write_midifile` say about the call signature?